# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') in Product Category Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have Write code to bring category data into category page by using parameters but it fails. I am using
react-router-dom@6. Now I need help, how to resolve it in react. I have made ProductCategoryPage and component in productDetails part where a route get all products according to category.

```
src/pages/ProductCategoryPage.jsx

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import FooterDesktop from "../components/common/FooterDesktop";
import FooterMobile from "../components/common/FooterMobile";
import NavMenuDesktop from "../components/common/NavMenuDesktop";
import NavMenuMobile from "../components/common/NavMenuMobile";
import Category from "../components/ProductDetails/Category";
import axios from "axios";
import AppURL from "../api/AppURL";

class ProductCategoryPage extends Component {
  constructor({ match }) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Category: match.params.category,
      ProductData: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    // alert(this.state.Category);
    axios
      .get(AppURL.ProductListByCategory(this.state.Category))
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ ProductData: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="Desktop">
          <NavMenuDesktop />
        </div>

        <div className="Mobile">
          <NavMenuMobile />
        </div>

        <Category
          Category={this.state.Category}
          ProductData={this.state.ProductData}
        />

        <div className="Desktop">
          <FooterDesktop />
        </div>

        <div className="Mobile">
          <FooterMobile />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductCategoryPage;
```

Comment: have u tried this ? `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Category: props.match.params.category
    };
}`

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but it gives me same error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')